# QueueUserAPC not working unless used immediately after thread creation?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm having some difficulty using the API function `QueueUserAPC`. Basically, I created a new thread that just loops using `WaitForSingleObject` on an `Event` object I created. I wanted this thread to sort of be a 'lone' worker thread that I can assign random function calls to that I need processed asynchronously..

However, when I create the thread, the only time `QueueUserAPC` will work is *directly* after the thread is created. If I insert say, `Sleep(2000);` right after `CreateThread`, then place `QueueUserAPC` after Sleep, it will not execute the function, even though it works if I do it before `Sleep` (right away).

I've tried using a different handle to the thread, i've tried resetting the event object, checked returned value of `QueueUserAPC` when it doesn't work (it equals 1, which MSDN says non-zero result is successful operation).

I don't quite know what to do about this. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

J.R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  WaitForSingleObjectEx().  Unless one of the 'Ex' alertable wait calls is used, the APC will not be dequeued and run by the thread.  If the wait returns WAIT_IO_COMPLETION - an APC has been executed by the thread.  Typically, some kind of loop is used to ignore that completion:

```
while(WAIT_IO_COMPLETION==WaitForSingleObjectEx(waithandle, INFINITE,true));
// do signalled stuff
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that got it working. I didn't realize I was using the wrong wait call.

Comment: Also, MSDN: 'If an application queues an APC before the thread begins running, the thread begins by calling the APC function' - so the 'working is directly after the thread is created' is explained too :)

Comment: WFSOE has *three* arguments.  The last one, missing in the snippet,  is the important one.

Comment: @HansPassant - right - maybe I should have looked it up :(  Aayway, thanks, edited in the bAlertable flag.